# Generate unique Ids during registration

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I want to generate unique IDs for Employees on registration.
The Ids are going to be used in real time situations which will be shared by users/employees ,so there should not be conflict.
Some thing like bank accounts which are always unique.
The IDs should not be incremental.
All Ids should be random.
I will save the generated  IDs in database and want to ensure that if new employees are registered they get the unique IDs(not already saved in database).

If any error occurs during saving of new Employee ,then I should be able to handle that situation(means generating an ID will not mean it is consumed.until it is saved in database it can be reused or recreated by the ALGO)

What is the best approach and way to handle this situation?

Comment: Have MySQL use a surrogate key, but let your Java layer have an EmployeeIdFactory class that encapsulates the rules and behavior you want.  The Employee class will have both the persistence id and the generated id from the factory.

Comment: Why must the length be configurable?

Comment: @Rainbolt because I am going to use the same concept to generate Ids for other situations also.

Comment: @Niks Are you saying that the existence of "other situations" creates a need for "configurable length IDs"? I'm not sure I follow...

Comment: @Rainbolt okay,That was the cause of confusion So I have removed it.

Answer (score 2):

To generate a random ID you can also use a simple customable Java method implementation:

```
public String idGenerator(int length) {
    char[] chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEF"
            + "GHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890".toCharArray();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int l = 0; l < length; l++) {
        char c = chars[random.nextInt(chars.length)];
        sb.append(c);
    }
    String id = sb.toString();
    return id;
}
```

...and before adding a new employee with specific ID check the database for it's eventual occurrence.

The very efficient way in avoiding ID repetition in all sorts of databases, is using in ID's a current date string, say: `yyyyMMdd-SomeRandomString`.

Comment: I wanted to avoid the database hit for verification before commit.Don't know if it is possible.

Comment: your answer is not exactly what I want for my situation.

Comment: @Niks Why do you want to avoid the database hit? There's no performance problem I can see anyhow. You won't create millions of unique ids per day. What about simply use the function [UUID](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid)